# How to get Schema of RDD in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

As we use `PrintSchema()` to get schema from Dataframe.
How can we get Schema of below RDD in PySpark.

**Second Question** – Do we have function like `df.info()` for RDD in pyspark ?

`rdd.collect(10)`

`['age,gender,miles,debt,income,sales', '28,0,23,0,4099,620', '26,0,27,0,2677,1792', '30,1,58,41576,6215,27754', '26,1,25,43172,7626,28256', '20,1,17,6979,8071,4438', '58,1,18,0,1262,2102', '44,1,17,418,7017,8520', '39,1,28,0,3282,500', '44,0,24,48724,9980,22997']`

Comment: `df.schema` helps?

Comment: RDD does not have a schema. so, you don't have any method to show its characteristics. it can ingest whatever you give it.

Comment: @samkart, it makes sense. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Mario, Thank you for your response, but My question is specific to RDD not dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Since you have already collected your rdd so it is now in the form of list and it does not remain distributed anymore and you have to retrieve data form the list as we do normally in list. And since it is not in dataframe so we dont have any schema for this list.

Question 2: df.info is a function of pandas but it can be access by this method

[image]

for further you can read this

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.info.html

Comment: So before using collect() action, is it possible to get schema of RDD ?

Comment: no RDD is not a dataframe. You can schema if you have it in dataframe.